# Subscription to realtime alerts for events impacting a planned route

Tags: notifications, here-api, live, traffic, alerts

Pre-requisite:

Communication is between AI on our servers and HERE servers, NOT between an app and HERE servers. This is because we would like integrate realtime travel duration estimation into our decision making process on server and then propose actions to user

Scenario:

A trip from A to B is planned for tomorrow to get a plane in B airport. Arrival time is 10:30am, AI says it’s alright
A incident happens on highway 30mn before leaving start position, AI should be notified of 10mn delay as it may cause difficulties to be on time
While on the road, AI is getting informed that the delay will be 45mn due to seriousness of incident. This is challenging to be on time at airport to catch the plane and alternative routes/modality are proposed.

Question: is there any way to register for alerts for a specific trip/routing ? Is it possible to provide a webhook ?

Google propose commuting alerts which is kind of capabilities we would like to have. We would like to avoid pinging every x minutes to check for changes as it may explode API calls quota and it is also stupidly inefficient for both HERE and us.

Any thoughts ? :)

[edit]: got some insight that Fleet Telematics API may be a start of answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no API that sends out traffic incident information. It would have to be a polling mechanism to periodically check for changes. Either to the Traffic API to get traffic incident information, or the Routing API to calculate the travel time of specific routes.